# Unexpected Authorization Request in Workflow C2QB WF3.0

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

We have a multi-tenanted/multi-domain app and we're looking at publishing on IPP.  Because of the multi-domain nature our configured endpoints in the App setup are generic and users are then redirected to their specific account once their identity is established.

The issue is with C2QB WF3.0.

The test steps are:

1. go here: https://appcenter.intuit.com/Home/MyApps/
2. on the "Launch My Apps" tab, click the app

Expected Result:

the Sign In screen for the app is displayed

---

The requirement is:

1. if not still signed into the app, sign in screen is displayed
2. if still signed into the app, take user into the app

The issue is that the even if the user is currently logged into our application, it still requests authorization as per this message:

"domain" is requesting some information from your Intuit account

By approving this request "domain" will be able to access your:

- Name
- Email Address

---

The workflow that it is actually following is to perform a callback to our connect url.  The normal way to determine which account the callback is coming from is via the realmId, but this is not received from Intuit and therefore it needs to be requested. Once a user has completed this authorization, it will not ask again. It should be noted that we're not actually requesting a name or an email address as the screen suggests.

We've been informed by Intuit that it should not request authorization and it is not part of the workflow.

We're wondering if anyone else has encountered this problem and if there is a workaround for it.

Comment: The realm can only be fetched with OpenID when the user/realm is connected to your app.  I believe the confusion here is between OpenID and OAuth authorization screens.  The OpenID authorization is expected in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

We discussed with the Engineering teams and they confirmed what Pete has mentioned above. This is not a bug and please follow the steps as Pete has mentioned.

Comment: It is not quite clear what the _correct_ steps are.  Is this behavior correct as I have outlined, because the review team are telling me that it is not.  I should be clear that it seems to ask twice.  Once when you connect and then once again, the first time you navigate between the our app and QBO.  Then it doesn't ask again.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replicate the 'access your app with appcenter flow', you have be either logged in QBO online company file in same browser session or navigate to the app via blue dot menu from your application or run your application from localhost(.net) and then go to Appcenter and login there on same tab and then click on your app.

Since your desktop application is running, your code will be hit.
You will then get the second Auth screen only for authorizing your company file. After authorization your realm will be set in a cookie and in the code you can see its value. You can replicate this behavior via firebug and see the qbn.parentid cookie value has the realm after authorization is done.